# redirecting to a URL after facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to redirect my page after successful login to a new url..

```
<?php
      include_once "fbmain.php";
    $config['baseurl']  =   "http://localhost:8080/index.php";;

    // login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($fbme) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(
        array(
            'next'      => $config['baseurl'],
        )
      );
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'display'   => 'popup',
            'next'      => $config['baseurl'] . '?loginsucc=1',
            'cancel_url'=> $config['baseurl'] . '?cancel=1',
            'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday',
        )
      );
    }

    // if user click cancel in the popup window
    if (isset($_REQUEST['cancel'])){
        echo "<script>
            window.close();
            </script>";
    }

    if ($fbme && isset($_REQUEST['loginsucc'])){
        //only if valid session found and loginsucc is set

        //after facebook redirects it will send a session parameter as a json value
        //now decode them, make them array and sort based on keys
        $sortArray = get_object_vars(json_decode($_GET['session']));
        ksort($sortArray);

        $strCookie  =   "";
        $flag       =   false;
        foreach($sortArray as $key=>$item){
            if ($flag) $strCookie .= '&';
            $strCookie .= $key . '=' . $item;
            $flag = true;
        }

        //now set the cookie so that next time user don't need to click login again
        setCookie('fbs_' . "{$fbconfig['appid']}", $strCookie);

        echo "<script>
            window.close();
            window.opener.location.reload();
            </script>";
    }

    //if user is logged in and session is valid.
    if ($fbme){
       header("Location: http://localhost:8080/main.php");
       exit;
    }

?>
```

However, it loads up the page inside the window login popup box, why is this and how do I load it so that it is in the main page.

Comment: You need to use javascript and test the response of FLogin, then decide the course of action (in your case window.location=http://localhost:8080/main.php )

Comment: mind showing some code below?

Comment: You only gave the PHP code here, the html/js would be more important now... It's highly dependent on your code. But in theory you should have a handler for exactly this scenario. In the unlikely event you don't we'll still find a solution, just post the js

Comment: I am using the same exact code as posted http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/create-facebook-popup-authentication-window-using-php-and-javascript/ at the very end there is index.php

Answer (score 0):

I have don this using facebook javascript api.

```
FB.init({
appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', 
status: true,
cookie: true, xfbml: true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
window.location.href='/app/home.php';
});
```

Comment: this is irrelevant with the question.. I am asking with the php-sdk

Comment: the reason I went with the php-sdk is that because with the javascript I can't seem to change the button type

Comment: Initially I tried with php-sdk but it was less flexible for me. So I went for javascript api.. I am not sure how it can be achieved using php-sdk. Did you tried changing the button using custom styles in your stylesheet..?

Comment: Tried marking it !important.? Or give the styles at the end of the page. For me its working here

Comment: could you show some code of your css and how hypertext for the login?

Comment: I have a  <span class="facebook">
           <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
         </span> and it does show me the custom button, but when I click it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
if ($fbme){
       header("Location: http://localhost:8080/main.php");
       exit;
    }
```

to the beginning of the script

You can also take out the `display'   => 'popup',` and set up a redirect uri, so people install the application and then go back to the original site, that way they will be redirected after succesfully install.

Answer (score 0):

"next" don't work, but "redirect_uri" do the job!

```
$params = array( 'redirect_uri' => 'http://yourdomain/fb_api/login_success.php' );
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```